# Xcode Installation Fatally Crashed My Mac

Tags: macos, crash, xcode

I borrowed a macbook with mountian lion today and I put a dmg of xcode on a flash drive and tried to install it but it crashed the mac and the mac WILL NOT load. It always goes to the crash screen when it starts up. It will log on into safe mode however. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you did and include the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Does the version of Xcode you're using come with a pkg installer ?

The Xcode version for Mountain Lion can only come from the App Store and is a standalone Xcode.app application.
To install it, just copy Xcode.app to /Applications or download it from the App Store

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: if you don't install the correct version of Xcode it may not run well. Which Xcode version do you try to install ?

Comment: Thanks that helps with the first part xD But now I just need to get this Mac fixxed because it just keeps crashing